# Adding a new field to Nutch + MongoDB datastore

Tags: mongodb, nutch

I am running Nutch 2.3.1 configured with MondoDB (using Gora) + Elasticsearch and would like to add a new field to the storage database NOT the index.

I am able to add a field to the elasticsearch index using a custom plugin but would like to add it to the mongodb record for each website.

I've added the field to the ./conf/schema.xml file and to ./conf/gora-mongodb-mapping.xml - The field does appear in the index but not in the mongo record..

Here'e a snapshot of my plugin:

```
public class AddNewField implements IndexingFilter {
...
@Override
  public NutchDocument filter(NutchDocument doc, String url, WebPage page)
      throws IndexingException {
        //adds the new field to the document
        doc.add("mynewField", "HelloWorld");
    return doc;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem ? if yes then please share it